# How should this SQL query be constructed? (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've never had to check for something like this before, so I'm hoping y'all can help. I'm not sure if it's best to create a temporary table, then check if an item is in it or if there's a better way.

Each row in the table represent an object that may have a parent. The parent is stored in the same table. In this example, the parent_id field holds the primary key of a row's parent. I'm trying to select all rows in the table which have the type column set to a particular value and whose parent rows have a 'z' in the field_b column. The part in parenthesis obviously needs work...

```
SELECT s_id, s_text, s_parent_id
FROM sections 
WHERE s_derivedtype >= 10000 AND
```

if this returns anything

```
SELECT s_id
FROM sections
WHERE s_id = {the s_parent_id from the first query) AND s_flags LIKE '%z%'
```

I've updated this to hopefully be easier to read...

What's the most efficient way to do this? I'm expecting something like 100k rows returned out of 18m in the table, so decent performance is non-trivial.

Comment: Provide the schema and small set of example data: "the parent_id field holds the primary key of a row's parent" sounds confusing. Is this some form of EAV or is it just explained awkwardly?

Comment: (I believe you just want a self-join like `FROM table1 AS c JOIN table1 AS p ON c.parent_id = p.id`, but I'm not in a guessing mood today.)

Comment: That's probably on the right track. I haven't posted the complete schema, but have hopefully made this a bit clearer as to what I'm asking.

Comment: Is there only a single immediate parent -- 1 child to 1 parent -- or are you looking for a recursive option?

Comment: Non-recursive. Thanks for the quick help everyone! Joining the table with itself did the trick. I've done many joins on tables in the past, but it unfortunately didn't occur to me to join a table with itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT t1.key_field, t1.field_a 
FROM tbl AS t1 
WHERE t1.type = 1 AND parent_id = (SELECT t2.id FROM tbl AS t2 
                                    WHERE t2.id = t1.parent_id
                                      AND t2.field_b LIKE '%z%')
```

or

```
SELECT t1.key_field, t1.field_a
FROM tbl AS t1 
INNER JOIN tbl AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.parent_id
WHERE t1.type = 1
AND t2.field_b LIKE '%z%'
```

Comment: It turned out to be a decent case for the subquery. Thanks TI.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT key_field, field_a 
FROM
    t s
    inner join
    t p on p.key_field = s.key_field
WHERE
    s.type = 1
    AND p.field_b LIKE '%z%'
```